# How to make multiple variables from one string

Tags: python, variables

I have a string containing a few variables that I would like to store.

```
data = '{name:ItCameFr0mmars,id:2110939,score:2088205,level:43,l
evelProgress:35,kills:18412,deaths:6821,kdr:2.70,kpg:12.03,spk:
113.42,totalGamesPlayed:1530,wins:913,loses:617,wl:0.60,playTim
e:2d 15h 1m,funds:2265,clan:TyDE,featured:No,hacker:false,follo
wing:0,followers:3,shots:117902,hits:38132,nukes:6,meleeKills:3
77,createdDate:2019-03-13,createdTime:21:38:39,lastPlayedClass:
Triggerman}'
```

I want to assign a variable for each bit of data. For example:

```
level = 43
kills = 18412
```

and so on.
Is there a way to do this, as each `example: number` would become a variable with that number stored? Also? how could I make a dictionary for it?

Comment: Don't create individual variables. Create a dictionary with key-value pairs.

Comment: What produced that string? It doesn't make any sense to use a poorly designed custom format when standard alternatives like JSON exist.

Comment: If the string doesn't contain the newlines you presented here, a one-liner could look like this: 'structure = {item.split(':')[0]:item.split(':', 1)[1] for item in data[1:-1].split(',')}'` (but doing `split` twice isn't the most beautiful way).

Comment: If it is an attempt on inventing your own storage format, note that there exists a very similar one, [JSON](http://json.org), which Python can read-write out of the box: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html. That format requires you to use some quotation marks, it would look like `data='{"name": "ItCameFr0mmars", "id": 2110939, "score": 2088205, ..., "createdDate": "2019-03-13", "createdTime": "21:38:39", "lastPlayedClass": "Triggerman"}'`

Comment: Can you clarify if you have control over the data, or if it comes from some external source?

Comment: It is coming from an external source

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic parser:

```py
for name, val in [item.split(':', maxsplit=1) for item in data.strip("{}").split(",")]:  
    globals()[name] = val

print(featured)
```

If you want to do this in a function. Just replace `globals` with `locals`.

Usually it is better to put it into an object:

```
class Data(): 
     def __init__(self, data): 
         for name, val in [item.split(':', maxsplit=1) for item in data.strip("{}").split(",")]: 
             setattr(self, name, val)

obj = Data(data)
print(obj.featured)
```

Comment: Note that 1) you're not really answering OP's request for creating individual variables (which is good though) and 2) if you need to write your own parser, you're doing it wrong in the first place…

Comment: That's okay, just based on the surrounding `{}`, and the fact this is some player data, my bet is that the next step will be having a list of them `[{},{},...]`, and then you are starting to develop a full-blown parser for some misunderstood JSONish ...thing.

Comment: I think writing your own parser is okay, if this data comes of a source you can not control. But I agree, that if you can control the dataformat, you should definitely use somethink like Json here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it like a dictionary like this

```
data = {"name":"ItCameFr0mmars","id":2110939,"score":2088205}
```

So you can get each value based on its key.

```
data["id"] will be 2110939
```

And if you want to print all them, you could write

```
 for key,value in data.items():
     print(key,":",value)
```

But I guess this is not what you wanted to do?